# JPA: Having lists on both ends without infinite loop

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to link two entities via `Set` properties like:

Entity A:

```
Set<Group> groups
```

Entity B:

```
Set<Filter> filters
```

However, I keep getting errors like infinite recursions. What is the best way to do this with JPA?

Comment: Are you using Mapping?

Comment: Yes I am trying to map the entities. Looks like `manytomany` does not work on both sides but none of the example on the web seem to work as well.

Comment: Check [JPA many-to-many relationship causing infinite recursion and stack overflow error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43481353/jpa-many-to-many-relationship-causing-infinite-recursion-and-stack-overflow-erro) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It goes into infinite recursion because both your entities call each other and it will never stop. 
Try adding

```
@JsonManagedReference(value = "group-filter")
Set<Group> groups
```

and

```
@JsonBackReference(value = "user-card")
Set<Filter> filters
```

above both the sets in your entities. It is used to warn spring not go into infinite recursion.