# OneToMany relationship causing infinite loop using JPA

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I've searched a bit before posting this question and i've tried adding @JsonIgnore on the ManyToOne side, on the OneToMany side as well, but nothing works. I'm defining two classes and their relationship as follows:

Cidade class

```
@Entity
public class Cidade implements Serializable {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8653970141174181222L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String nome;
    private String estado;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cidade", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Cliente> clientes = new ArrayList<Cliente>();
    
    public Cidade() {
        
    }
    
    public Cidade(String nome, String estado) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.estado = estado;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    
    public String getEstado() {
        return estado;
    }

    public void setEstado(String estado) {
        this.estado = estado;
    }

    public List<Cliente> getClientes() {
        return clientes;
    }

    public void setClientes(List<Cliente> clientes) {
        this.clientes = clientes;
    }                   
}
```

And Cliente Class:

```
@Entity
public class Cliente implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9148095834550183273L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String nome;
    private String sexo;
    private String dataNascimento;
    private Integer idade;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_CIDADE", nullable = false)
    private Cidade cidade;
    
    
    public Cliente() {
        
    }
    
    public Cliente(String nome, String sexo, String dataNascimento, Integer idade, Cidade cidade) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.sexo = sexo;
        this.dataNascimento = dataNascimento;
        this.idade = idade;
        this.cidade = cidade;
    }

    public Cliente(Integer id, String nome) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getSexo() {
        return sexo;
    }

    public void setSexo(String sexo) {
        this.sexo = sexo;
    }

    public String getDataNascimento() {
        return dataNascimento;
    }

    public void setDataNascimento(String dataNascimento) {
        this.dataNascimento = dataNascimento;
    }

    public Integer getIdade() {
        return idade;
    }

    public void setIdade(Integer idade) {
        this.idade = idade;
    }

    public Cidade getCidade() {
        return cidade;
    }

    public void setCidade(Cidade cidade) {
        this.cidade = cidade;
    }
    
    
}
```

Everything works as expected but when i try to get one Cliente using a rest api, it causes an infinite loop. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `@JsonBackReference` on your `@OneToMany` field and use `@JsonManagedReference` on your `@ManyToOne` field. See example code below:

**Cicade class**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "cidade", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JsonBackReference
private List<Cliente> clientes = new ArrayList<Cliente>();
```

**Cliente class**

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_CIDADE", nullable = false)
@JsonManagedReference
private Cidade cidade;
```

Comment: It gives me this error: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, you have to write

```
@JsonBackReference(value = "cidade-cliente")  // ----------------> Unique value
private List<Cliente> clientes = new ArrayList<Cliente>();
```

In the Cicade class and,

```
@JsonManagedReference(value = "cidade-cliente")  // ----------------> Unique value same as that of the Cliente list of Cidade class
private Cidade cidade;
```

In the cliente class.

Also, Check this out [JPA: Having lists on both ends without infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59299430/jpa-having-lists-on-both-ends-without-infinite-loop/59300432#59300432)